# Which scope represents this in a JavaScript function within an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript code that looks like the excerpt below.
At line,

```
this.orgBusinessKey = this.user.noaOrganisationList[0].businessKey;
```

will the `this` scope contain the `user` instance passed as parameter to the constructor?

I've read this [post on `this` scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work), but, according to my belief, at `setAdmin` `this` refers to `MyClass` which does not include (or does it?) the parameters like `user` passed to the constructor.

```
export interface IUser {
  noaOrganisationList: IOrganisation[];
}

export interface IOrganisation {
    id?: number;
    name?: string;
    businessKey: string;
}

export class MyClass {

  orgBusinessKey: string = '';

  constructor(public user: IUser)
  {
    this.setAdmin(user);
  }

  setAdmin(user: IUser): void {
    if (user && user.noaOrganisationList && !_.isEmpty(user.noaOrganisationList)) {
      this.orgBusinessKey = this.user.noaOrganisationList[0].businessKey;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> setAdmin this refers to MyClass which does not include (or does it?) the parameters like user passed to the constructor.

You're right that `this` is a reference to the instance of MyClass that's currently being constructed. However, since you marked the parameter as public, typescript **will** put the user on `this.user`. Marking parameters to a constructor as public (or private for that matter) is a shortcut that typescript provides for assigning the parameters onto the instance of the class.

If it helps, here's what the transpiled version of your code looks like:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var MyClass = /** @class */ (function () {
        function MyClass(user) {
            this.user = user; //  <------------------ SEE THIS LINE
            this.orgBusinessKey = '';
            this.setAdmin(user);
        }
        MyClass.prototype.setAdmin = function (user) {
            if (user && user.noaOrganisationList && !_.isEmpty(user.noaOrganisationList)) {
                this.orgBusinessKey = this.user.noaOrganisationList[0].businessKey;
            }
        };
        return MyClass;
    }());
    exports.MyClass = MyClass;
});
```